# How to understand this construction?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

I read a headline in The New York Times that went like this:

Times Past:

We’re diving into The Times’s archives with the help of a professional.

my thought revolve around "Times Past". what is "Past" in it a noun? I think "Times" is the trademark right? so is "Past" a noun being modified by "Times" thus the past of Times?

Answer (score 2):

'Times' is a plural noun; 'past' is an adjective meaning 'gone by or elapsed in time'. In *times past* (or past times), we rode on horses; now we ride in cars. An archive contains old or historic things. Past things. The publication is the '*New York **Times***'. The title combines an obvious meaning as I just described, and also a play on words (i.e. both '**times** that are **past**' and 'the **past** of the ***Times***'). Writers of newpaper headlines and article titles are fond of wordplay, and, possibly, none more that those employed by the *New York Times*.

Comment: so can I use an adjective in front of a noun this way?

Comment: I didn't know onde could use "in times past", only "in past times"

Comment: @cynthiagrillas - Some adjectives can be before or after a noun; 'past' is one of those.